# how can i set wallpaper from my nativa application thru iOS 4.0 using Photo Library?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I have made one application in iOS 4.0.In that application using Photo Library i am getting image in ImageView and from the Button Click I want to set that image as a iPhone Background so how can I do this using iOS 4.0?

Comment: You can't. That's not part of the API.

Comment: Perhaps the op was simply hoping to learn something and not stating that he was an expert.  I don't believe an honest question deserves a down vote.

Comment: I bet this could be done using a private framework on a jailbroken device with the right entitlements.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, neither iOS 4.0 (nor even 5 for that matter) allow you to change the user's background from within an application, only from the Settings application. The most you could do is prompt a user to save the image to the Camera Roll, open the Photos application, and set it themselves.